# weld-osgi getting started

Tags: java, osgi, jboss7.x, weld

Recently i read [this documenentation](https://docs.jboss.org/weld/reference/1.2.0.Beta1/weld-osgi/design-notes/html_single/)  and also [this announcement](http://in.relation.to/Bloggers/NotOneTwoWeldReleases1110FinalAnd120Beta1), basically targetting the weld-osgi releases.

I am really interested in how to get this to work in JBoss AS 7.1.x. Can someone please point me to a solution that works?

Thanks

Comment: I would appreciate if you could share what you mean with "get this to work"? I assume you want to bundle (aka include) it in your application and deploy onto JBoss, don't you? Or perhaps you want to tweak JBoss a bit so it runs with the new Weld releases? Just curious.

Comment: The former is my intention, not the latter

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Weld-OSGI release introduced Weld SPI changes. There is currently no stable JBoss AS release supporting the new SPI. 
An option is to build the current JBoss AS 7 master from source. Then you should be able to upgrade to 1.2.0.Beta1 simply by replacing weld jars.

Comment: I think i will just have to wait for release before i proceed. or make do with IBM WEBSHPERE. Thanks for the reply though

Answer (score 0):

Sure thing: [Helloworld OSGi quickstart](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS7/Helloworld+OSGi+quickstart)

Comment: The example listed in the page above (from my own understanding) does not support CDI Annotations for OSGI as well as other cool features listed in Link 1 of my question. I am specifically interested in setting up a project that uses Weld-osgi jars. so that annotations like [code]@Publish, @OsgiService, e.t.c can be used